# Determine the coordinates of the vector $(4,3,2,1)$ in the basis $\{(1,0,0,0),(1,1,0,0),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,1,1)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I did this

$$(4)(1,0,0,0)+(3)(1,1,0,0)+(2)(1,1,1,0)+(1)(1,1,1,1) = (10,6,3,1)$$

The right answer is $(1,1,1,1)$. I don't understand. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: You're supposed to do it the other way. You have to determine coefficients $A$ through $E$ so that
$$(A)(1,0,0,0)+(B)(1,1,0,0)+(C)(1,1,1,0)+(D)(1,1,1,1) = (4, 3, 2, 1)$$

Comment: You need a linear combination of the basis vectors (1,0,0,0), (1,1,0,0), (1,1,1,0) and (1,1,1,1) which gives (4,3,2,1). You have found the vector whose coordinates in that basis are (4,3,2,1), which is a different thing. They question assumes (4,3,2,1) is in the usual basis.

Answer (score 1):

The question is perhaps ambiguously worded. There are two interpretations:

1. A vector has coordinates $(4,3,2,1)$ in the basis $((1,0,0,0),(1,1,0,0),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,1,1))$. What are its Cartesian coordinates? (This is the version that you answered.)
2. A vector has Cartesian coordinates $(4,3,2,1)$. What are its coordinates in the basis $((1,0,0,0),(1,1,0,0),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,1,1))$? (This is the version with answer $(1,1,1,1)$.)

I automatically assumed version $2$ when I read the question; you automatically assumed version $1$. I think the question is at fault here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the scalars $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ such that you have

$$ v_1(1,0,0,0) + v_2(1,1,0,0) + v_3(1,1,1,0) + v_4(1,1,1,1) = (4,3,2,1)$$

In this case, you have that $v_1 = v_2 = v_3 = v_4 = 1$ which forms a vector $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4) = (1,1,1,1)$

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates $(a,b,c,d)$ of $(4,3,2,1)$ in that basis are the real numbers such that $a(1,0,0,0)+b(1,1,0,0)+c(1,1,1,0)+d(1,1,1,1)=(4,3,2,1)$. Then we arrive at the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
a+b+c+d=4\\
b+c+d=3\\
c+d=2\\
d=1 \end{cases}$$

Solving the system $Ax=(4,3,2,1)^T$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1& 1\\
0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ gives the answer $(1,1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should start with

$(4,3,2,1) = 4(1,0,0,0) + 3(0,1,0,0) + 2(0,0,1,0) + 1(0,0,0,1) \ (*)$,

which I suspect is what you *meant* to write when you wrote

$(4)(1,0,0,0)+(3)(1,1,0,0)+(2)(1,1,1,0)+(1)(1,1,1,1)=(10,6,3,1)$.

$$$$

So you could write each of the bases $\ (1,0,0,0),\ (0,1,0,0),\ (0,0,1,0)\ $ and $\ (0,0,0,1)\ $

*in terms of* (i.e. as a linear combination of) the vectors you were given,

$(1,0,0,0), (1,1,0,0), (1,1,1,0)\ $ and $\ (1,1,1,1)$,

and then solve $(*)$.